# Overwrite File in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this Google Script:

[Gmail2GDrive](https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/)

and it works like a charm except that I need it to overwrite the existing file as I'm intending to link to it and share it.

How would I need to modify this script?

Comment: What script? If you're looking for debugging help, you need to include the MCVE in the question itself.

Comment: @tehhowch Sorry I bungled the link. I corrected the post. The script I'm using is here: https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/

Comment: The code you are having problems with should be in your question - not on some 3rd party site. That said, do not just post your code verbatim. We aren't here to fix your production code. Construct an MCVE from your code, and edit that into your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really overwrite a file in Google Drive. (Not that I am aware of.)
Each file has its own unique ID which means the name of the file is kind of irrelevant. (When attempting to override a file in the Windows Explorer terminology.)

That being said I have used this in the past to move files using Google App Script. Hope it helps:

```
  //Get the ID of the Destination Folder
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Your Folder ID");

  //Create a copy of the Merged Sheets Temp and move to the Desitnation Folder.
  DriveApp.getFileById(FileToMove.getId()).makeCopy("Give the File a name", destinationFolder);

  //Move Merged Sheets Temp to Trash
  var tempMergeDocument = DriveApp.getFileById(FileToMove.getId()).setTrashed(true)
```

Comment: You can absolutely overwrite a file in Google Drive via Apps Script

Comment: @tehhowch Would you mind adding some code to show how you would override a file in Google Drive?

Comment: @tehhowch https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/2h_Yie3EoZo/xDjOWq1Wm7MJ